# Adding 2 lines in text file stanza

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed, awk

I have a text file divided in stanzas.
Each stanza starts with a [keyword] and ends with a blank line. Something like this:

```
[keyword1]
param1 = value1
param2 = value2
param3 = value3

[keyword2]
param4 = value4
param5 = value5
...
```

I need a script (probably a one line command will work) to insert 2 lines immediately after a given `[keyword]`. Lines to be inserted are like the above couples:

```
param = value
```

I was thinking about using `sed` with in place editing plus a backup copy file just in case.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, `sed` sounds like the right choice:

```
sed -i.bak '/^\[keyword1\]/aparam = value\nparam = other' your.file
```

`awk` can do it, excepting the in-place editing part:

```
awk '1;/^\[keyword1\]/{print"param = value";print"param = other"}' your.file > new.file
```

If you not care about using a big gun like `perl` for such a small task:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '$_.="param = value\nparam = other\n"if/^\[keyword1\]/' your.file
```

The later one will work in `ruby` with 1 character modification:

```
ruby -i.bak -pe '$_+="param = value\nparam = other\n"if/^\[keyword1\]/' your.file
```

`python` solution is somehow lengthy (probably worsened by my knowledge's weakness):

```
python -c 'import sys,fileinput;[sys.stdout.write(line+("param = value\nparam = other\n" if line=="[keyword1]\n" else "")) for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1,backup=".bak")]' your.file
```

Again without the in-place editing, but `bash` and `ksh` can do it too:

```
while IFS='' read -r line; do
  echo "$line"
  [[ "$line" == '[keyword1]' ]] && {
    echo "param = value"
    echo "param = other"
  }
done < your.file > new.file
```

With `ed` is simple to edit in-place, but I know no way to create backup:

```
ed -s your.file <<< $'/^\[keyword1\]/a\nparam = value\nparam = other\n.\nwq'
```

Comment: you are my personal wiki-hero! :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `vim` as your editor, you can set up abbreviations in your `.vimrc` as follows:

```
:abbr key1 [keyword1]^M^Iparam1 = value1^M^Iparam2 = value2^M^Iparam3 = value3^M
:abbr key2 [keyword2]^M^Iparam4 = value4^M^Iparam5 = value5^M
```

Now, in any file, in insert mode, if you type `key1`, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, you'll see:

```
[keyword1]
       param1 = value1
       param2 = value2
       param3 = value3
```

If it's the sort of thing you do often, and repetitively, `vim` abbreviations can ease the pain.